Domain of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R},f(x+y)+f(x)f(y)=4xy,f(\frac{1}{2}) \ne 0$.What is the parity of $f(x-\frac{1}{2})$?
According to this

$f(x+y)+f(x)f(y)=4xy$

i have figure out that

$f(0)=-1$
$f(-\frac{1}{2})=0$
$f(\frac{1}{2})=-2$

now i need to figure out the parity of $f(x-\frac{1}{2})$

i let $z=x-\frac{1}{2}$, so i think i just need to verify the relationship between $f(z)$ and $f(-z)$ and then i will get the answer.

left is my effort

$z=x-\frac{1}{2}$, $x=z+\frac{1}{2}$
$f(z) + f(x)f(-\frac{1}{2}) = 4(z+\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{1}{2}) \quad (f(-\frac{1}{2})=0)$
$f(z) = -2z-1$
so i according to $f(z) \ne f(-z)$ and $-f(z) \ne f(-z)$ get the conclusion that $f(z)$ is not even or odd, or $f(x-\frac{1}{2})$ is NOT EVEN or ODD.
but the ANSWER gives me that $f(x-\frac{1}{2})$ is ODD
where did i go wrong?


So if $f(z) = -2z-1$, what is $f !\left(x-\frac 12\right)$?

The parity of the function $g(x) = f(x-\tfrac12)$ is tested by evaluating $g(-x) = f(-x-\tfrac12)$.  If you define $z=x-\tfrac12$, then this would be $f(-z-1)$.  What you wanted is to define $z=x+\tfrac12$.

Or just let $y=-\frac 1 2$, and find $f(x-\frac 1 2)$ directly?

As $f(-1/2) = 0$, then
$$
g(-x) = f(-x - 1/2) = 2x = -f(x - 1/2) = -g(x)
$$
where $g(x) = f(x - 1/2)$. So $g$ is odd.
I believe that your confusion comes from the composition of functions, and that you were looking for the parity of $f$ instead of the parity of $g$.

yes, my confusion comes from the composition. In addition, Is that to say the graph of the g(x) is shifted by f(x) $\frac{1}{2}$ unit right?

In addition, there is two functions $f:x \rightarrow y , g:x \rightarrow y$so the parity is about to $f$ and $g$ itself, is not about how to choose the x , is that right?

Yes that’s it. For instance the parabola $x^2$ is even, and the parabola $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ is symmetric along the $x = \frac{1}{2}$ vertical line. Parity is about the function, not the variable.

sincerely thank you :-)

You can find out that $f(x)=-(2x+1)$ which implies $f(x-\frac12)=-2x$ and the answer is obviously ODD.
